# How does an affiliate URL or link track sales of a product?

Tags: database, url, backend, change-tracking, affiliate

I'm just curious, how do I create a URL that if I give to a blogger or business, how will it track if a person purchased an actual product and not just clicked on the link. How would that look in a database of products etc...?

What I'm trying to do is have businesses sign up for my service, and the service sells their products. But I have to provide a link to track the sales and clicks and stuff. How would this work?